# Google Sheets: keep track of days spent in different countries

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-dates

I have prepared a Google Sheet that lists all flights I have taken in recent years, alongside the departing and arriving country:

| Date & time | From | To | Outbound country | Inbound country | Days in inbound country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10/10/2020 12:45 | LGW | FCO | United Kingdom | Italy | 36 |
| 15/11/2020 17:45 | FCO | LGW | Italy | United Kingdom | 34 |
| 19/12/2020 20:00 | LGW | FCO | United Kingdom | Italy | 22 |
| 10/01/2021 17:45 | FCO | LGW | Italy | United Kingdom | 153 |
| 12/06/2021 20:20 | LGW | FCO | United Kingdom | Italy | 15 |
| 27/06/2021 12:45 | FCO | LGW | Italy | United Kingdom | 99 |
| 04/10/2021 21:35 | LTN | FCO | United Kingdom | Italy | 13 |
| 17/10/2021 14:10 | FCO | LHR | Italy | United Kingdom | 20 |
| 06/11/2021 06:55 | LGW | FCO | United Kingdom | Italy | 14 |
| 20/11/2021 10:20 | CIA | STN | Italy | United Kingdom | 21 |
| 11/12/2021 18:25 | LHR | FCO | United Kingdom | Italy | 51 |
| 31/01/2022 14:05 | FCO | LHR | Italy | United Kingdom |  |

I have then created a Pivot Table that summarises the days spent in each country per calendar year:

| Year | Italy | Jordan | United Kingdom | USA | Grand Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 | 49 | 5 | 216 | 21 | 291 |
| 2019 | 48 |  | 306 | 15 | 369 |
| 2020 | 58 |  | 307 |  | 365 |
| 2021 | 93 |  | 293 |  | 386 |
| 2022 |  |  | 0 |  | 0 |

It seems to be working well. The problem is dealing with the end of the year.
I will not take a flight every year on the 1st of January, so there will always be days in January that are counted as previous year's days. For example the days in 2022 are counted as 2021.

Any ideas on how I can deal with the "end of year" problem?

Here's the link to the Google Sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1seH0A13AqhY41_mCcgqncHdoCWqU21lDnKQwtz3oCZM/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be many ways to arrive at an answer to this question. I don't claim that the methods used in *this* answer are necessarily the most efficient, but they *do* work, and someone (maybe the OP) maybe able to improve upon them.

[image: Pivot]

---

**Summary**

- **Design**: The pivot table is created manually (Insert, Pivot Table). A screenshot of the design attributes is included below.
- **Source**: The source data is a query which consists of six stacked queries

`=query({ query({'Entry/exit details'!E2:E51,'Entry/exit details'!G2:G51,'Entry/exit details'!L2:L51}); query({'Entry/exit details'!E2:E51,'Entry/exit details'!G2:G51,'Entry/exit details'!M2:M51}); query({'Entry/exit details'!E2:E51,'Entry/exit details'!G2:G51,'Entry/exit details'!N2:N51}); query({'Entry/exit details'!E2:E51,'Entry/exit details'!G2:G51,'Entry/exit details'!O2:O51}); query({'Entry/exit details'!E2:E51,'Entry/exit details'!K2:K51,'Entry/exit details'!P2:P51}); query({'Entry/exit details'!E2:E51,'Entry/exit details'!G2:G51,'Entry/exit details'!Q2:Q51})}, "select Col1, Col2, Col3 label Col1 'INBOUND COUNTRY', Col2 'YEAR', Col3 'Days'")`

- **Queries**: these represent calculations for specific year/trip combinations:

  - #1: The first trip record
  - #2: The last trip record
  - #3: Trip records where the year is the same as the previous trip and the next trip
  - #4: The last trip in any year-the days for the departure year
  - #5: The last trip in any year-the days for the following year
  - #6: The first trip in any new year

---

**Structure#1-Trip Years**

The first step is to identify, for each record, each of three years. This was done by adding additional columns on the "Entry/exit details" sheet.

- The year of the trip - `=arrayformula(year(A2:A51))`
- The year of the previous trip - `if(isdate(A2)=false,"",year(A2))`

  - the formula for the first trip is slightly different - `=if(isdate(A1)=false,year(A2),year(A1))`
- The year of the next trip - `=if(isdate(A3)=false,year(A2),year(A3))`

[image: Year info]

---

**Structure#2 - Trip days**

The second step is to recognise the six trip elements, and to calculate the number of days that relates to each.

- #1 1st record - `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(row(indirect(address(2,1,3)&":"&address(COUNTA($A$1:A),1,3)))=2, DATEDIF(A2:A, A3:A, "D"), 0))`
- #2 Last Record - `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(row(indirect(address(2,1,3)&":"&address(COUNTA($A$1:A),1,3)))=COUNTA($A$1:$A), DATEDIF(A2:A, today(), "D"), 0))`
- #3 Year is same for Year/Last/Next:
  `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(row(indirect(address(2,1,3)&":"&address(COUNTA($A$1:A)-1,1,3)))=2,0,IF(row(indirect(address(2,1,3)&":"&address(COUNTA($A$1:A)-1,1,3)))<COUNTA($A$1:$A),if(ArrayFormula((year(A2:A)=year(A1:A))*(year(A2:A)=year(A3:A))),DATEDIF(A2:A, A3:A, "D"),0))))`
- #4 Last trip in a year-Days for balance of This Year:
  `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(row(indirect(address(2,1,3)&":"&address(COUNTA($A$1:A)-1,1,3)))<COUNTA($A$1:$A),IF(row(indirect(address(2,1,3)&":"&address(COUNTA($A$1:A)-1,1,3)))=2,0,if(arrayformula((year(A2:A)<>year(A3:A))),datedif(A2:A,eomonth(date(year(A2:A),12,1),0)+1,"D"),0))))`
- #5 Last in a year-Days till the first trip Next Year:
  `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(row(indirect(address(2,1,3)&":"&address(COUNTA($A$1:A)-1,1,3)))<COUNTA($A$1:$A),IF(row(indirect(address(2,1,3)&":"&address(COUNTA($A$1:A)-1,1,3)))=2,0,if(arrayformula((year(A2:A)<>year(A3:A))),DATEDIF(date(year(A3:A),1,1),A3:A,"D"),0))))`
- #6 First trip in a Year:
  `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(row(indirect(address(2,1,3)&":"&address(COUNTA($A$1:A)-1,1,3)))=2,0,IF(row(indirect(address(2,1,3)&":"&address(COUNTA($A$1:A)-1,1,3)))<COUNTA($A$1:$A),if(arrayformula((Year(A2:A)<>Year(A1:A))),DATEDIF(A2:A, A3:A, "D"),0))))`

[image: Days calculations]

---

**Structure#3 - Linking trip years to trip days**

Each the query has three fields:

- The Inbound Country - common for every query.
- A year calculation and a day calculation

  - Years and Days are combined as follows:

    - 1st Record = Year of trip (Column G)
    - Last Record = Year of trip (Column G)
    - This Year/Last/Next = Year of trip  (Column G)
    - Last trip in a year (This Year) = Year of Trip (Column G)
    - Last trip in a year (Next Year) = Year of Next Trip (Column K)
    - First trip in a Year = Year of Trip (Column G)

---

**An Example**

Trip departure: 22 December 2018
Inbound country: Italy
Next departure: 7 January 2019
OP calculation: 16 Days

Breakdown using this answer:

- Last trip in a year (This Year)= 2018 - 10 Days (22/12/2018 to 31/12/2018)
- Last trip in a year (Next Year)= 2019 - 6 days (1/1/2019 to 7/1/2019)
- Total days = 16 but breakdown: 2018=10, 2019=6.

---

**Source**

[image: Query]

---

**Pivot Table design**

[image: pivot design]

Comment: Thank you so much @Tedinoz for the incredibly detailed explanation and the potential solution! I will keep this open just for another couple days then I will accept your answer if there aren't easier ones.

Comment: GREAT and nice work!

Answer (score 0):

I think that your better option is to add a new row when the year change, like the one I added in you sheet, see this picture:

[image]

Comment: Two things: 1) what does "IDEM" mean (Columns D & E)? Using your example, wouldn't you need to have "Italy" in Column E? 2) Wouldn't the "departure date" for the inserted row be the first day of the "new year" since it is a continuation of a stay in the same Inbound Country? This would create a split of 21 days (2021) and 30 days (2022).

Comment: Thanks @Daniele I was also thinking to do that initially as a solution - and I could create a custom airport code that would signal a new year...

Comment: I think you are right @Tedinoz it would need to be the first day of the year

Comment: @Tedinoz
 yes, you are correct on both :) my new row was intended only to show its position into the sheet

Answer (score -1):

This is excellent, exactly what I was looking for. I am now trying to adjust it for how many days I'm in each country per financial year 01-Apr to 31-Mar. If you have a moment and could point me in the right direction on how to do this, that would be great,

thanks again,
Raj